# Errors when writing to Application Support directory

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, nsfilemanager

I've seen this question asked a dozen times on here and yet the solution do not seem to solve my situation.

I have some content that needs to be stored in the 'Application Support' directory, but I continue receiving errors when trying to write there.

```
func assetFilesDirectory(asset: Asset, shouldCreate: Bool) -> URL? {
        do {
            let applicationSupportFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let folder = applicationSupportFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("\(asset)")
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folder.path) {
                if shouldCreate {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }

            return folder
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

When this code runs, I keep getting the following error:

> "You don’t have permission to save the file “asset-backgrounds” in the folder “Application Support”."

I've tried toggling the value for the **create** parameter in the following line, but I get the same error with that too, just referencing the *Application Support* directory and *Library* instead.

```
let applicationSupportFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

I haven't seen any reason why this should make any difference API-wise, but as information, I am running this code on the tvOS platform (physical device). There is no information indicating that *Application Support* should be permission-restricted on tvOS though.

Comment: This line throws the error if I am trying to create a folder inside of 'Application Support' - try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

Comment: Oh, sure, I see. Sorry about that. But it's so confusing: how can an _asset_ be a _path component_? What's needed here is a string.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - Asset is an enum of type String

Comment: Well, I tried a string and it worked fine for me. Could it be that you are confusing things thanks to the Asset?

Comment: I will try this in a few hours, when I'm back on that machine - thank you!

Comment: However I still think the error is coming from elsewhere, since you are not attempting to save a file.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your Asset (whatever that is) with a string and it worked fine:

```
func assetFilesDirectory(name: String, shouldCreate: Bool) -> URL? {
    do {
        let applicationSupportFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let folder = applicationSupportFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(name)
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folder.path) {
            if shouldCreate {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                print("ok")
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        return folder
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

I called

```
let url = self.assetFilesDirectory(name: "test", shouldCreate: true)
print(url)
```

and I got back `"ok"` and the URL `file:///blahblahblah/Library/Application%20Support/test` which is just what one would expect.

Comment: I have copied this code, but it is still returning the same error for me. The function is returning nil and does not print "ok". I'm starting to wonder if "Application Support" is actually restricted on tvOS, despite not being documented as so. What platform were you able to get this code working on?

Comment: I tested on the tvOS simulator. I don't have a real Apple TV. :(

Comment: Thank you for all of your support - it looks like this is an Apple bug. Upon running your code on a simulator, it works flawlessly immediately. I've tried running it on multiple physical Apple TVs, however, and the same exception is thrown consistently. I've opened a bug report with Apple to get this resolved.

Comment: OK but please send me an Apple TV so I can test this for myself :)))))))